# How do I run an Android app on my device?

Tags: android

RTFM is the most natural reply but I have tried that and it did not work.

This is what I have done so far:
1. Install all the necessary USB drivers from the vendor's site. The USB device is properly installed.
2. Add `android:debuggable="true"` to my manifest
3. Tried `adb devices` in command prompt and it shows the device as connected
4. Enabled USB debugging via `Developer Settings`

Still, my phone is **not detected in Eclipse**

What is going wrong ?

I am using Windows 7 32 bit and trying to connect a Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) with the latest firmware :)

Comment: Not to mention, restarted Eclipse.

Comment: If using eclipse, I think you don't need to add `android:debuggable="true"` to manifest

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: So your device list in eclipse is empty?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Absolutely.

Comment: That is kind of weird as both uses the same adb instance (normally) which means if your device is listed in command line, it should be listed in eclipse as well. Maybe use the good old MS magic: shut down the pc, reboot the phone, pray a minute and boot the pc again...

Comment: @LittleChild same issue i was facing earlier then i installed a software i.e Moborobo ...after that it was working properly

Comment: @Gaurav I already have `Samsung Kies`

Comment: same issue brother try dis once it will work

Comment: restart both phone and pc xD

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic worked xD

Comment: ^^ funny how eclipse is really not good, I suggest you to try android studio. So far it seems to be really good

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with my Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300). I solved this issue after "Factory Data Reset". Now when i connect my phone with USB ,Eclipse shows my device perfectly.

Hope its helpful to you...

Answer (score 1):

My friend had similar problem, solution was restarting adb server. Try running:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

from command line.

Comment: try sudo adb start-server instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try Run-> Run Configurations-> Target in eclipse and change it to always prompt to pick device. This worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the driver problem. Just install the drivers properly and try reconnecting it.

[image] this is a driver for S5830 similarly you should install drivers for your device

Answer (score 0):

Download Samsung Kies mini And Than Try To Connect Your Device.

Answer (score -2):

Install the software Moborobo 
and then

Try Run-> Run Configurations-> Target in eclipse and change it to always prompt to pick device.